# Intellij idea not showing "Dependencies" tab on Project Structure - Modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module

I just clean installed IntelliJ IDEA and opened a Java project.

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> go to "Project Structure" -> "Modules".

However I cannot see the tabs that should have "Sources/Paths/Dependencies".

I just want to import some ".jar" to my project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Try removing your module and creating new one.

If you don't know how to remove a module see link bellow:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/removing-modules-from-a-project.html

To know how to create a new module see this link:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-a-java-module.html

Comment: This does solve the problem for me. Even though it suggests a misconfiguration in the IntelliJ client.